# Xamarin.Android with MapBox: Compilation failed with XA4212

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mapbox

I have a Xamarin.Android project and want to use MapBox for navigation. They do not provide a SDK for Xamarin, so I use the Naxam Bindings. (GitHub: https://github.com/NAXAM/mapboxnavigationui-android-binding)

When I compile a test code copied from their demo code, I run into the following error:
XA4212: Type Com.Mapbox.Services.Android.Location.LostLocationEngine implements Android.Runtime.IJavaObject but does not inherit Java.Lang.Object or Java.Lang.Throwable. This is not supported.

By researching I found out that this error can be changed to a warning by  putting the following in my project file:

```
<PropertyGroup> <AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject>false</AndroidErrorOnCustomJavaObject> </PropertyGroup>
```

But if I do that, the compilation fails with: "'java.exe' exited with code 1".

the build log shows:
Type com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\90\lp\1\jl\gson.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.class, obj\Debug\90\lp\2\jl\gson-2.8.0.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.class

I also filed an issue to Naxam which you can find here:
https://github.com/NAXAM/mapboxnavigationui-android-binding/issues/12

I tried to compile their project myself, but it can't resolve the dependencies, so it doesn't compile either.

Is there anything I can do futher or has anyone an idea?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: Have you figured this out ? I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

About Using Mapbox in Android, you can install **Naxam.Mapbox.Droid** firstly, then also need to these dlls.

[image]

Mapbox requires some permissions, add these permissions in AndroidMainfeast.xml file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.mapboxdemo" android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<service android:name="com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.telemetry.TelemetryService" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

You can also pull the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-android-binding) and add reference to it.

Comment: Hey :) thanks for your answer. When I do that, I get the following error message: java.exe exited with code 1. Details from the build log in the next comment

Comment: Error in obj\Debug\90\lp\1\jl\gson.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.class: 
Type com.google.gson.annotations.JsonAdapter is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\90\lp\1\jl\gson.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.class, obj\Debug\90\lp\2\jl\gson-2.8.0.jar:com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.class